# How do you limit the Azure Staging Environment from accessing Resources

Tags: .net, azure, azure-worker-roles

Are there any patterns for deploying and upgrading Azure Worker Roles. We are currently using our CI Server to deploy our worker role to Staging and then to Swap to Production.

Is it possible to prevent the Staging role from accessing resources (ServiceBus, DB, etc.) so that it isn't processing jobs until it is promoted to Production.

Answer (score 1):

The most common pattern is to have a configuration setting that you would change when you swapped to production.  The worker role code would only do work if that configuration setting had a certain value.

But for a worker role that does background work would it matter if both staging and production were picking up jobs?  There are a lot of scenarios where it does matter, but typically for background worker roles that are backwards compatible it doesn't matter which one picks up the work.

Comment: How would that work in case of VIP swap? Are you saying, we do VIP swap and switch the configuration setting manually indicating that the app is now running in production slot?

Comment: I think @GauravMantri already [answered this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261586/azure-detect-staging-vs-production)

Comment: The configuration change takes some time because it honors update domains which means there's a timeframe when some instances have already received the change and some haven't and this is before the swap. So this approach just makes the timeframe shorter but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, VIP swap and then update the configuration setting.  This means that there may be a small time window where no instances are picking up work items, which may or may not be acceptable depending on the architecture.  But as I mentioned and as sharptooth mentions in his answer, the best solution is to architect the service so that both deployments can pick up the work items.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. They both will work on the same storage until you first swap the deployments and then stop the older one. You should handle multiple instances working over the same storage anyway so this shouldn't be a big deal to prevent them from processing the same items in the storage.