# Switch Azure ConnectionString based on Staging or Production

Tags: database, azure, connection-string

Is there a way to use different ConnectionString, based on Production or Staging environment ? How ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Staging or Production Instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328462/staging-or-production-instance)

Comment: I am interested to know more about your scenario. Would u please give the scenario so we can provide you the best guidance. I happen to work in similar scenario where staging deployment was tied to database X, and while making staging to production, the connection string needed to change to point to database Y. is that your issue?

Comment: It's exactly the same scenario you describe. When I deploy on the staging I want to use database X because it's like a draft but when I deploy on production I want to use the final database Y. But I want to use the same Datacontext name but with different Connectionstring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly recommend that first, you don't treat the "staging lot" like a traditional staging environment. It should instead be considered a temporary area to "smoke test" a deployment before it goes live. If you have need for a persistent staging environment, instead use a different hosted service to fullfill that need.

When you do this, it then makes it a fairly simple matter to maintain multiple cloud service configuration files, one for each environment.

Comment: I understand that this is just a "smoke test", however the changes to my website mean that I now need to update some database values and table structures during the app startup. I can't change the live database (as then live would not be able to run), but I can't test the staging website becaue it needs these values. Is there a way around this, or do I just need to accept the limitation and plan to not be able to do a "smoke test"?

Comment: When you deploy changes to Windows Azure, its going to attempt to do "rolling upgrades". This means that unless you've specifically set the number of upgrade domains to '1', you'll have both the old and new copies of your web site existing side by side, a situation which will commonly cause errors. To address this, you really need to consider making your solutions smart enough to handle database differences, or consider using a "we're making upgrades, please wait" style upgrade behavior (a simple DNS change would work).