# detect production or staging in cloud service in azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to detect if I am in staging or production ? 
there is a RoleInstance class but it doesn't have a field for this metter.

There is a microsoft code but it's complicated. the link is https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/CSAzureDeploymentSlot-1ce0e3b5#content , but I don't understand if the hostedServiceName in the code is my project name, cloud project name, or cloud service name, and what is thrumbnail, where do I get it from and how do I register it in the azure ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  There are a lot of questions here, You should try and ask specific questions, rather than broad general ones. Take a look at the faq stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @StuartSiegler - actually this question seems pretty direct-and-to-the-point, as when you deploy a cloud service (web/worker roles), there's a staging and a production slot. HOWEVER: This question has been asked, and answered, numerous times. So it's a duplicate. The OP simply needs to search for **[azure] staging**.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about the same long time back which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/03/16/programmatically-finding-deployment-slot-from-code-running-in-windows-azure/ though I must admit the code is quite old (so please refer to the latest documentation). HTH.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Staging or Production Instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328462/staging-or-production-instance)

Comment: @DavidMakogon - Perhaps, but as soon as OP added , "and what is," and "how do I..."

Comment: I have seen all the answers that have been posted... the problem is i couldn't implement them. i have looked at the post by  Gaurav Mantri but i failed when reading certificateData because i have no field called by this name in the cscfg or csdef. how do i get this certificateData ? the subscription id i fetched from the azure portal... is it because i am using cloud service instead of web service ?