# How to know if an Azure function is running in a slot

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

Can a function know if it's running in a slot?

I would like to prevent a function to be executed if in "staging" slot.

> **Updated**
>
> Base on the answer from Bruce (thanks again buddy), I wrote that blog post http://www.frankysnotes.com/2017/09/how-to-know-when-azure-function-is.html

Comment: I'm very late to this, but if you're looking to disable a function you can use app settings, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function. To disable a function in a particular slot, you can make this app setting a slot setting. There's no need to write any code, or check any environment variables, in your function to achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Staging or Production Instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328462/staging-or-production-instance)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can a function know if it's running in a slot?

Per my understanding, you could check the `APPSETTING_WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME` environment variable in your code, and the value would be **Production** when your function is under production while the value would be the slot name when your function is under a slot as follows:

[image]

[image]

For C#, you could leverage the following code for retrieving this variable:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Additionally, for F# you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-fsharp#environment-variables), for JavaScript you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#environment-variables).

Comment: Wonderful, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: This env variable doesn't seem to exist any more :(

Comment: The environment variable is "WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME" as of this date.

Comment: I can see both `APPSETTING_WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME` and `WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME` variables in Kudu as of this date