# Get the current slot the azure app service is running on?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have an azure app service, with a production slot and staging slot.
We often deploy to staging, do some testing and swap to proc.
We do NOT use slot specific settings because they cause the app to restart upon swapping and we want swapping to be instant and transparent to users.

Question: How can I determine programmatically what slot the app is currently running on, as of right now?

We are aware of the WEBSITE_HOSTNAME environment variable, however it is useless since its value doesn't change upon swapping (as verified in Kudu). Also, I believe that a process must restart in order to refresh the value of an environment variable that was changed after the process started.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328462/staging-or-production-instance/35775500#35775500)?

Comment: I said no slot specific settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the azure app service slot name on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50147803/getting-the-azure-app-service-slot-name-on-startup)

Comment: Not a startup. At anytime.

Comment: @Clement Is it useful with `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]`?

Comment: This requires an http context. Also, does it change when swapping?

Comment: @Clement In my test, yes it changes as expected.

Comment: Thanks, that seems promising, although I'd prefer a solution that doesn't depend on http context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Staging or Production Instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328462/staging-or-production-instance)